# Finding previous file names

Tags: windows-8.1, filenames

I was wondering if it is possible to find the previous name of a file after renaming it, or even find out if the file was renamed in the first place.

I've found one of my old USBs which may have some useful files for a project I'm currently working on, but the current file names are not too descriptive. I would like to know if I renamed the files at some point, and if so what the original names were.

Comment: There is not any kind of "History" of a file system on windows if that is what you mean - the only one way to achieve this are the backups :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default windows file systems doesn't keep track of such changes. Some kinds of files do have internal fields for that. Maybe look at the attributes of a file (Right Click => Properties => Details) and have a look at them. Otherwise you'd have to setup shadow copies or use third party programs that might help with that. If you Click on a folder and check its Properties you can see a tab that's called "Previous Versions" in theory you could set that up put it's usually not a good idea for portable storage devices. It would keep a certain amount of history for a directory/file.

Comment: Hi Seth, do you know of any third party programs that might help with this? I did have a look at the "previous versions" options and there doesn't seem to be any previous versions listed. Would this suggest that the file was not actually renamed at any point, and therefore using a third party option would be a waste of time?

Comment: This would suggest you didn't setup the mechanism for it to work. It does require additional disk space as previous versions are kept and so on. Click on the "How do I use previous versions?" link in the dialog. It won't help you with your current Problem. If it's a project you're working on consider using something like GIT or Subversion to keep track of changes (including renames). Otherwise regular backups you can compare against would be the thing. There are countless solution for that.